# How can I write proper tests for a local notification interface?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, rx-swift

I'm using `Swift 5`, `Xcode 10.2`
I support iOS versions 10 and up

I have a notification model I can initialise with some data (title, body, actions, etc) and a static class with a function that takes in a notification model and shows a local notification based on its contents. It's all `RX` and the caller of the function can subscribe to the return value and it will fire an event when the user interacted with the notification (tap, dismiss, custom action, etc).

Now I want to test this class, I'm very new to both writing tests and `RX` so I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around this. From outside the class all I have is that one function.
I was thinking of what I actually want to test, and it comes down to showing the notification at all and if the mapping mechanism to a strong typed user interaction goes alright.
Another problem is that I don't always know if the permission for showing local notifications was granted, and if it's not been granted how to test if everything works.

**How can I grant the permission to show notifications in a test?**

**How can I test wether the notification was shown?**

**How do I interact with the notification in a test?**

Sorry for asking three questions for the price of one, but they are so related I figured it's better for everyone not to clutter the site with three very similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're out of bounds for unit testing here, and what you're looking for is UI testing.

If you want to unit test, you need to create testable classes where you could specifically test small behaviors such as does your init create values you expect, was a certain method invoked after a chain etc.

For actual testing if the notification was shown and interacting with it, you would have to dig into UI testing, where the actual how-to is dependant on how you show the notification etc. UI tests are pretty straightforward to start with, you just fire up the record method, then later clean up and add some additional logic for checking.

These are decent places to start learning about UI testing:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/09-ui_testing.html

https://www.raywenderlich.com/960290-ios-unit-testing-and-ui-testing-tutorial

https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/getting-started-with-xcode-ui-testing-in-swift